# Meaning and usage of "Queens rules"

Tags: meaning

In one podcast I've stumbled upon the following dialog (two hosts discussing new version of software, one of them like it other - not, both of them males):

> xxx: Ok, we both have tried that version on that weekend and now lets talk about it. Queens rules?
>
> yyy: Yes.
>
> xxx: The thing that I liked most is...
>
> yyy: But on the other hand...

After that it looks like normal discussion. In that context it sounds like a question which you may ask your opponent just before yours argument/battle. Also I could incorrectly recognize that phrase but it sounds like "Queens rules".

Comment: Some context, please!

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet, done.

Comment: Since the phrase depends on something which you may have "incorrectly recognised", it would be really helpful to include a link to the podcast and the timestamp of the phrase.

Comment: @Andrew: I almost thought this was General Reference, but Janus's comment and evidence from Google Books that ["Queensberry Rules" is significantly less common in AmE](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Queensberry+Rules%3Aeng_us_2012%2CQueensberry+Rules%3Aeng_gb_2012&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=10&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CQueensberry%20Rules%3Aeng_us_2012%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CQueensberry%20Rules%3Aeng_gb_2012%3B%2Cc0) convinced me otherwise.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's [**Queensberry Rules**...](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marquess_of_Queensberry_Rules)

> *a code of generally accepted rules in the sport of boxing. They were named so because John Douglas, 9th Marquess of Queensberry publicly endorsed the code.*

The term is often used (usually, but not always *facetiously*) in more general contexts. It normally has the general sense of *"We agree to settle our differences in a gentlemanly fashion"*, but arguably in OP's exact context it has the more specific sense of...

> *"We agree to take turns throwing a punch (making a point in a debate), then allowing the other contestant to parry that point (rebut it by reasoned argument) before he makes **his** next point."*

Comment: +1 – never heard about this before (which makes sense, since I hate boxing). Live and learn. :-)

Comment: @Janus: I've never been into boxing myself, but as a teenager I was terrifically impressed by [Cassius Clay / Muhammad Ali](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muhammad_Ali#Exile_and_comeback) and his principled stand against the establishment. No matter how much you may deplore his chosen "career", I think you have to admit he was/is a great man (he's barely still "with us" today). To my mind the way he was treated by vindictive/uncaring vested interests US society is far worse than anything he did in the ring.

Comment: ...even *before* I was a teenager, I was familiar with *"Queensberry rules!"* as an an injunction/exclamation. In the context of a playground fight, for example, it pretty much just meant *"No kicking, biting or scratching"* - certainly not *"Combatants must wear boxing gloves, fight in 3-minute bouts with no wrestling allowed, etc."*.